# How to make a rotating menu on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, rotation, android-viewpager

I am trying to code a rotating menu for a children's app. The idea is to allow kids to change between different scenarios, each containing different animals.

The animals are represented on a round surface and, as the kids swipe right or left, the globe rotates with old animals fading out and new ones fading in, kinda like this:

[image: image1]

The result I'm trying to reach is similar to the iOS iCarousel wheel effect.

[image: pages rotating as if on a wheel]

Toxic Bakery's ViewPagerTransforms library (https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms) has an effect called Rotate Down that is very similar, but I haven't been able to adjust it to my needs. The pages roll in on their own instead of rotating on a common axis.

I've also tried the CursorWheelLayout (https://github.com/BCsl/CursorWheelLayout), but there are many performance issues due to the images, making the app crash.

My most recent attempt has been the SpinMenu (https://github.com/Hitomis/SpinMenu), which is great. The fragments do rotate on a common axis, but only while zoomed out. I haven't figured out a way of making it change pages (as a ViewPager would) with the fragments rotating in and out of view.

**Any suggestions on what to do to reach the desired result?**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found:

1) Implement the CarouselView library: https://gtomato.github.io/carouselview/

2) As CarouselView extends from RecyclerView, create the layout for the CarouselView to inflate (which I called carouselview_item):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

3) As CarouselView extends from RecyclerView, create a CarouselViewAdapter extending from RecyclerView.Adapter

```
public class CarouselViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarouselViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Fragment> list;

    public CarouselViewAdapter(List<Fragment> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CarouselViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.carouselview_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CarouselViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = list.get(position);
        holder.bind(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    // In case you are using, let's say, RxJava for getting the list
    public void setObjects(List<Fragment> list) {
        if (list.size() == 0) {
            this. = list;
        } else {
            this.list.addAll(list);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private T example;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // Find your views:
            // example = itemView.findViewById(R.id.example);
        }

        public void bind(T object){
            // Bind the info you need to the view:
            // example.setInfo(object.getInfo)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4) Set things up on the activity, including the desired Transformer and also the adapter:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CarouselView carouselView;
    private List<Fragment> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initAssets();

        Fragment object1 = new T(/* necessary parameters, if any*/);
        Fragment object2 = new T(/* necessary parameters, if any*/);
        Fragment object3 = new T(/* necessary parameters, if any*/);

        list.add(object1);
        list.add(object2);
        list.add(object3);

        carouselView.setTransformer(new WheelViewTransformer());
        carouselView.setAdapter(new CarouselViewAdapter(list));
    }

    private void initAssets() {
        carouselView = findViewById(R.id.carouselview);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

It worked for me like that, although the performance isn't great due to the images I am using for now.

Enjoy!